# Is there a fast (and accurate) way to calculate the sample variance of a data-set till the n-th element?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, statistics, variance

I need to calcualte the sample variance of a data-set till the n-th element e.g.

```
x = np.random.randint(1, 7, 10)
--> [5 2 2 5 3 5 2 5 4 2]
```

The fast and easy way is using np.var(x) or a implementation of Welfords algorithm but those only calcualte the variance for the whole data-set.
For my aplication i need the variance element wise in an array so that in the n-th element it would be the variance with the first n-th data-points from the data-set.

For example:

```
x_var[2]
--> variance of [5 2 2]
--> 1.7320508
x_var[9]
--> variance of [5 2 2 5 3 5 2 5 4 2]
--> 2.0555556
```

My solution is to silce the array in to n arrays so that i can just use np.var on each of them for the running variance. This works but is incredibly slow.

```
for i in range(0,n):                                                
    x_var[i] = np.var(x[:i])
```

I already have a fast implementation of a running mean , so i have an array with the mean till the n-th element in the n-th entry, if that helps.

How would you solve this efficiently and accurately without silcing the array in n pieces?

Comment: Idk about pure numpy, but if you used pandas, then there's .rolling (for same-size window) and .expanding (for grabbing expanding windows like you do). https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to use `pandas` with [`expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.expanding.html) and [`var(ddof=0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.var.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.array([5, 2, 2, 5, 3, 5, 2, 5, 4, 2])

pd.Series(x).expanding().var(ddof=0).to_numpy()
```

output:

```
array([0.        , 2.25      , 2.        , 2.25      , 1.84      ,
       1.88888889, 1.95918367, 1.984375  , 1.77777778, 1.85      ])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would actually also go with the pandas approach. However, one possible solution using pure numpy that doesn't require slicing would be

```py
def running_mean(x:np.array) -> np.array:
    return np.cumsum(x) / np.arange(1,len(x) + 1)

def running_var(x:np.array) -> np.array:
    means = running_mean(x)
    return ((np.tril(x) - np.triu(means).T) ** 2).sum(axis=1) / np.arange(1,len(x) + 1)
```

So basically using the running mean funciton, but that into triangular matrices and doing the math from there. This could become slow though for large x due to creating those triangular matrices of size N x N.

Comment: That work than because i have arrays in the range of 10e6-10e8